# Date Range Picker codeigniter filter search

Tags: codeigniter, search, filter

I'm looking for Date Range Picker CodeIgniter filter search tutorial to buy can anyone help me with links thanks....

Answer (score 0):

You can use client side date pickers in your html form to pick start and end date on client side and use those values by submitting on server side in codeigniter active record query like in mentioned code.

```
$this->db->where('date >=',$first_date); 
$this->db->where('date <=',$second_date);
```